# Page reload after DatePicker Value Changed in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, datepicker

I am using Microsoft.Phone.Controls.DatePicker to pick a date in my form. Each time I select a date and press "Ok", the whole page reloads. Is there any way that can be used to avoid the page_load in my application after picking a date. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked for me: In your OnNavigatedTo method, run the functions you want only if you're loading the page for the first time.

```
  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
  {
     base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

     if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New)
     {
        // Your code here
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, you're actually navigating to a page in the same way you would using NavigationService. If you're redrawing your UI in OnNavigatedTo or Loaded, consider no longer doing so, as these are called when the DatePicker is closed.

http://www.codebadger.com/blog/post/2010/10/05/WP7-Development-Tip-of-the-Day-Page-Startup-Loaded-event-vs-OnNavigatedTo-method.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation last week and I solved it using a simple Boolean that checks if you are navigating to the page for the first time or from the DatePicker page.

```
public bool firstEdit { get; set; }

public TripEditVIew()
{
        firstEdit = true;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (firstEdit)
    {
           // init your page...

           firstEdit = false;
    }
}
```

I created a property named firstEdit that I set to true in the Constructor.
When you navigate to that view for first time you are going to trigger OnNavigatedTo function and you will be able to init your page with your init code. 
Do not forget to set to false the boolen property at the end of your init code.

When you returns from DatePicker Page you will trigger OnNavigatedTo function too, but this time is going to do nothing.